# URL with plus sign in it cannot be loaded

Tags: pyqgis

There is a formula parameter in URL continues with mathematical expression. I noticed if there is `+` char the layer cannot be loaded. I had similer error with `{`, `}` chars. Replacing them with `%7B`, `%7D` fixed it. They were before the `?` char which indicates parameters starts for get method.
I replace `+` with `%2B`, did not solve the problem.

I have used the following code to test.

```py
def add_layer(url):
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(url, "plus_sign", "wms")
    if layer.isValid():
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Is there I am missing with get method urls and `+` signs

---

More info:

```
url_on_pyqgis_side = "type=xyz&url=domain/endpoint/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D?formula=%28a%2Bb%29"%26"colors=[{"min":0,"value":[0,0,0]}"
```

With f12 I checked what the url looks like when qgis creates a request.

```
domain/endpoint/1/1/1/formula=(a+b)&%7B%22min%22:0.3,%22max%22:0.4,%22rgb%22:[255,193,122]
```

It looks like QGIS converts the delimiter characters on its own understanding before sending a request.

Comment: Replacing `+` with `%2B` should work, and I think the F12 view is translating it back to a `+`. But the nested quotes in `url_on_pyqgis_side` are not going to help, so fix those first

Comment: Nested quotes works just fine. I have connected to many other endpoints and displayed maps with them on qgis-plugin. The formula has `-`,`*`,`/` as well. Only `+` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like plus sign is the achilles tendon of url's in qgis.

Hex codes are manged by qgis but,
'+' is being used for space in url. So the conversation takes place on way

Answer (score -1):

Edit based on reread: My understanding was you needed to pass the plus signs to URL WITHOUT them being operators. Instead, to encode operators to URL, try urllib.quote(your.url,safe) where safe does not encode forward slashes and quotes.

---

Original Post:
You just have to escape special characters so python reads them as string rather than as operators. Use the format: url = r"myurl.com/xxx+yyy+zzz". The r takes care of escaped characters.

Comment: Python does not read "+" characters as operators in literal strings. You are probably thinking of backslashes which Python uses for escaping. That's a whole different thing though.

Comment: @bugmenot123 that actually is not correct. Adding r in front of quotes escapes all special characters. I tested just to make sure.

Comment: How and where did you test that? It sure does not do anything of the sort in Python: >>> `print(r"myurl.com/xxx+yyy+zzz")` -> `myurl.com/xxx+yyy+zzz`

Comment: My understanding is that OP is attempting to call a url to a map server where a plus sign is used as an operator in the url? If so, then the correct way to do this is to pass the url to server as a literal string with the plus sign included, which the server side should read as a plus sign (like this example https://help.mapsly.com/en/articles/5361172-url-parameters-in-formulas-of-map-layers-and-filters). If that's not correct, please let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: r" didnt worked. 

Plus sign is a part of equation which is a parameter that map server uses to produce image. The backend was originally a post method, which works fine for web application. I could not find a way to create layer from post service in qgis or pyqgis. So we add get methods to post.

Comment: @GolD. Did the update help? I was wrong with the original answer, I see that you needed something a bit different.

Comment: @JacksonDunn no sorry